# Restrict / control Laravel 5.4 API with custom API status response

Tags: php, api, laravel-5

In this case all the API's responses were 200. But the actual data structure returned does not match with the expected output data. For example:

---

```
The actual output response 
... status : 200
... data : "Oh no! I'm not the actual result"
```

---

```
The expected output
... status : 200
... data :  "Yes, I received"
```

---

The actual result still response 200,  but the result due to internet provider ... my API response does not returned as expected.

How to make my API response not returned as 200 or maybe is it can be integrate with `middleware` if it is not the right data structure then it return as my custom response code.

Comment: Can you post some code from your controller that returns the response?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to response other than 200? Then you could use something like this

```
return Response::json([
'data' => "Oh no! I'm not the actual result"], 422); // returns Unprocessable Entity status code
```